# How is this question on protobuf and RXTX too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Yesterday I posted up the following question: [How do I use Google protobuf to communicate over a serial port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356243/how-do-i-use-google-protobuf-to-communicate-over-a-serial-port) and it was closed this morning as "Too Broad."

No comments were posted to the question and as near as I can tell the stock feed back from the close banner is irrelevant because I included the relevant block of code that is likely the cause of the problem, i.e. there's a correct way of doing things and I suspect I'm not doing it right.

How exactly is this question "too broad?"

Comment: The [question cited](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17356243/230513) has been reopened.